# recursive function using joomla db object

Tags: recursion, joomla, recursive-query

I want to write a recursive function in joomla that get all the child level categories using a category id using joomla's jmodel's db object.Following is my code that I have written:

```
    function getChildCategories($type){
            $query = "SELECT id FROM #__cd_categories WHERE parent_id='$type'";
            echo $query."<br/>"; 
            $this->_db->setQuery($query);
            $list = $this->_db->loadObjectList(); 
            if ($this->_db->getErrorNum()) { echo $this->_db->stderr(); return false; }       
            foreach($list as $record){
               $this->childCategories[]= $record->id;
               echo $record->id."<br/>";
               return $this->getChildCategories($record->id);
            }

        return true;            
    }
```

So now problem is that, in joomla we use $this->_db_setQuery method and $this->_db->loadObjectList method , so in recursive call the result set, I think it overwrite, I think because the object is same. So can any one tell the way that how to overcome this problem? If you can solve this by using loop even that would be also very helpful for me.

I also think that once values are assigned to $list variable then that over write shouldn't be problem.So seems strange.Please tell if some one can tell me the way to do it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the issue is with the database object getting overwritten. It has been a bit since I have been struggling with recursive functions but I think the issue is with assigning the $list variable.

Should you not be returning that variable instead of boolean true like this:

```
function getChildCategories($type) {
        $query = "SELECT id FROM #__cd_categories WHERE parent_id='$type'";

        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $list = $this->_db->loadObjectList(); 
        if ($this->_db->getErrorNum()) { echo $this->_db->stderr(); return false; }  
        if ($list) {
            foreach($list as $record){
               $list->childCategories = $this->getChildCategories($record->id);
            }
            return $list;
        } else {
            return;
        }

}
```

Comment: Return can be any thing, in this case I don't need any return value as I am saving value in object property that is childCategories array, and where is problem with $list assigning?

Comment: Yah but the code you updated is no more a recursive function?

Comment: I think it is good effort but really unable to understand that ,how in every iteration of foreach you are assigning value to same variable. I think it will be override.?

Comment: That is the tricky part of recursive functions. In the end it will return what all the other "sub calls" have returned.